# include unicode character within long regex

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, regex-group, unicode-escapes

I have a regex:

```
/[a-zA-Zɑôáīúȑìêɑ͡iɑ͡uŋġḧn̐ƞġg̶̃čḣñt́d́ŕŕńȶv̈m̈ᵯǰɏæǽÿẇẏs̃śś̶]+/gm
```

which works great except there is one character I can't include (or that doesn't seem to work as expected when included). The character is (within) the last digit of the regex:

`ś̶`  // [it makes the cross-through (not easily visible in some fonts), in unicode it is `'COMBINING LONG STROKE OVERLAY' (U+0336)`]

my regex is capturing the character but splitting any word that contains it:

```
"mokk̇ś̶ḣô".match(/[a-zA-Zɑôáīúȑìêɑ͡iɑ͡uŋġḧn̐ƞġčḣñt́d́ŕŕńȶv̈m̈ᵯǰɏæǽÿẇẏs̃śś̶g̶̃]+/gm)

// == ['mokk', 'ś̶ḣô']
```

I've heard about [Unicode Property Escapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes) using `\p{UnicodePropertyValue}` with a `u` flag. Would that be useful here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be related to ś char. As you said your self, it's being captured.
The reason for the splitting is the lack of another char: k̇.

```js
console.log("mokk̇ś̶ḣô".match(/[a-zA-Zɑôáīúȑìêɑ͡iɑ͡uŋġḧn̐ƞġčḣñt́d́ŕŕńȶv̈m̈ᵯǰɏæǽÿẇẏs̃śś̶g̶̃]+/gm)
)
console.log("mokk̇ś̶ḣô".match(/[a-zA-Zɑôáīúȑìêɑ͡iɑ͡uŋġḧn̐ƞġčḣñt́d́ŕŕńȶv̈m̈ᵯǰɏæǽÿẇẏs̃śś̶k̇g̶̃]+/gm)
)
```

Comment: too many characters. Thanks a million, I missed it!

Comment: the k̇ś̶ always travel together, that's why I missed it